# Ways of constraining the localization of particules in AMCL?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry if there is already an answer out there, I may not have the proper keyword.
While using AMCL in far from optimal conditions (not so much features, cheap lidar), I am searching for ways to help the algorithm by putting constraints on where the particules can be.
For instance, I have forbidden areas where my robot is not allow to go, and therefore, I would like to tell the AMCL algorithm that no particules are allowed in these areas (these areas are not walls, and cannot be seen by the sensors, just logical obstacles taken into account by the planners).
Maybe special values in AMCL map?
Any clues?
If not I may implement it myself and share it if there is interest.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275851/ways-of-constraining-the-localization-of-particules-in-amcl?/) by [doisyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/25266/doisyg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the amcl code to add this constraint/advanced proposal you are talking about. I think one solution would be to modify the [sampling method](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/amcl/src/amcl/sensors/amcl_odom.cpp#L113)

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0